# Unable to call POST method using Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

Code as below:

```
public void loginPost(String url, String emailAddress, String password){
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap();
        params.put("email", emailAddress);
        params.put("password", password);
        JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject(params);
        String LOGIN_REQUEST_TAG = "LOGIN_REQUEST_TAG";

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, parameters, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d("Login Response:", response.toString());
                JSONObject responseOject = response;
                if(responseOject.has("data")){
                    try {
                        Log.d("Data Response", responseOject.getString("data"));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }else if(responseOject.has("error")){
                    try {
                        errorMessage = responseOject.getString("error");
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                                .setTitle("Error")
                                .setMessage(errorMessage)
                                .setNegativeButton("OK", null)
                                .show();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }else{
                    //Server error. Come back again later
                    Log.d("Server error", "Server Error");

                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.e("Error at login: ", error.getMessage());
            }

        });
        AppSingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest,LOGIN_REQUEST_TAG);

    }
```

All the parameters and URL are correct as I have checked it during debug. And everything works fine in Postman as well. However, the code above just wont go into `onResponse` method and I am not receiving any error. But it is giving a warning that `"responseOject"` is redundant. Am I doing it wrongly? Quite new to Android development.

Error:

```
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401
```

It is a POST API and I am using Request.Method.Post, why am I receiving that error?

Comment: Where are you calling `loginPost`?

Comment: And yes, it's redundant because you already have `JSONObject response`, so `JSONObject responseOject` is just a copy of it

Comment: when user clicks on a button

Comment: Can you add `Log.d` *outside of JsonObjectRequest*? Does it log there? Is the URL timing out? What is the URL you are setting?

Comment: @cricket_007 edited my question as above

Comment: 401 means Unauthorized, so somehow you need to pass in some Authorization, User-Agent or other information

Comment: @cricket_007 however, in POSTMAN, no auth is required.

Comment: I'm not sure without knowing the URL or seeing the request being handled by the server

Answer (score 1):

Before using the API test it in [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog). You will get a clear view of what is happening.
The error code 401 means you parameters are wrong. OR you are unauthorized to access that API.

Try this code for this type of call.

```
  private void callNetwork(final String email, final String password) {
        String json_object_request = "jsonObjectRequest";
        //Creating a string request
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.URL_LOGIN,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        if (response != null) {
                            parseData(response);
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                //Adding parameters to request
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);
                //returning parameter
                return params;
            }
        };

        //Adding the string request to the queue

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest, json_object_request);
    }
```